# SSL use symmetric or asymmetric?

Tags: java, ssl, encryption, private-key, encryption-asymmetric

So far what I understand:

1. Sender starts the handshake with server.
2. Server generates a pair of Public and Private key using asymmetric encryption and re-encrypt the Public key alone using symmetric encryption. And passes the Public key to the sender.
3. Sender encrypt the message using the Public key and sends the encrypted message to server.
4. Server decrypt the message using symmetric encryption and then decrypt the message again using the Private key.

Is this the right way how a SSL encryption works?? Please correct me.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it seems to ask a copy-paste from the [SSL/TLS wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security)

Comment: Getting short answers from Professionals is easy for understanding rather than reading the whole article in wiki.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin If that's what you think the wiki article really says, or if the OP does, you both need to read it again. It doesn't.

Comment: @Yithirash But what entitles you to get those short answers from professionals? Posting a lot of half-understood nonsense and then asking professionals to vet it is really just a waste of everybody's time. I've dealt with your questions below but you could have saved yourself some public embarrassment by doing your research properly in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Sender starts the handshake with server.

*Client* starts handshake with server.

> Server generates a pair of Public and Private key using asymmetric encryption and re-encrypt the Public key alone using symmetric encryption.

No.

> And passes the Public key to the sender.

No. It sends its *certificate* to the client and they then start a secret-key negotiation.

> Sender encrypt the message using the Public key

No. It uses a symmetric session key negotiated during the handshake.

> and sends the encrypted message to server.

Yes.

> Server decrypt the message using symmetric encryption

Yes.

> and then decrypt the message again using the Private key.

No.

> Is this the right way how SSL encryption works?

No.